# sencha hide show button

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Hi i am new to sencha and i try to find out how some things work in sencha architect /sencha touch.

i found a project http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/
and i try to make that in architect.

at this point i try to make the toolbar on top of my app. i have some buttons there that switch between my cards.

i want the button that goes to my first screen starts hidden so looks like back when i am at my second screen. i setted events for my buttons

```
this.setActiveItem(0);
```

and i tried

```
Ext.select("#mybutton1").hidden = true;
mybutton1.setVisible(false);
```

but they don't work...
any ideas?

also if anyone has any tutorial/ example about everything please advice...
thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hidden` property or `setVisible(false)` won't do it here.

Use `hide()` function.

Like this,

```
Ext.getCmp('buttonId').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Ext.getCmp('mybutton1').hide()
```